# How to get pexpect to enter "y" in response to input prompt

Tags: python, pexpect

I have a command line program that I'm running with pexpect, and it outputs this line:

```
‍♂️ Would you like to continue? [y/n]:
```

Then it hangs waiting for an input.

I want to enter "y" using pexpect and have the program continue.

I've tried

```py
pexpect.run("[COMMAND]", events={"[y/n]: ": "y"})
```

and various combinations of the string to capture, including `\[y/n\]`, as well as various combinations of the string to input, including `y\n`.

It appears to not work because the program doesn’t continue, but I don’t see an error message because it’s suppressed by pexpect, I think.

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but the cursor begins one space after the colon.

How can I get this to work?

---

EDIT:

With this code suggested by an answer, I'm able to see the error output:

```py
child = pexpect.spawn('command') 
child.expect('[y/n]:') 
child.sendline('y')
```

I'm getting `pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded.` because it looks like the regex isn't able to match.

```
buffer (last 100 chars): b'rty-1643399100\r\n\x1b[0m\xf0\x9f\x93\x8c Would you like to continue? [y/n]:\x1b[0m '
before (last 100 chars): b'rty-1643399100\r\n\x1b[0m\xf0\x9f\x93\x8c Would you like to continue? [y/n]:\x1b[0m '
after: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: False
pid: 43897
child_fd: 7
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.EOF'>
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile(b'[y/n]:')
```

This helped me troubleshoot and figure out I needed `\[y/n\]:`. Thank you!

Comment: Include newline in response as `y\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `pexpect.run("[COMMAND]", events={"[y/n]: " : "y\n"})` ?  According to the documentation and depending on your program the newline may be necessary.

Or, to be more generic and save, use

```
import pexpect 
child = pexpect.spawn ('command') 
child.expect ('[y/n]: ') 
child.sendline ('y')
```

Comment: Didn't do the trick, and there's no `pexpect.sendline`

Comment: I mean: 
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn ('command')
child.expect ('[y/n]: ')
child.sendline ('y')

Comment: I'm able to get the error logs with that! I've updated my question with what I'm currently seeing. I've also tested with `y\n`

Comment: Solved, thank you~